# Uploading a File to Google Drive with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I would like to use a visual basic desktop app to upload a file to Google Drive.  The main purpose of the app does much more, but this is a time-saving feature I need to add

I have downloaded the NuGet for Google.Apis.Drive.v2 and have added the following code:

```vb
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Services
```

I have a button to call my code:

```vb
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    CreateService()
    UploadFile(myFile)
End Sub
```

And then I have code to Create the Service and Upload the File:

```vb
Private Sub CreateService()

    Dim ClientId = "My ClientID copied from Google"
    Dim ClientSecret = "My Client Secret"   

    Dim MyUserCredential As UserCredential = _
    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() _
    With {.ClientId = ClientId, .ClientSecret = ClientSecret}, _
    {DriveService.Scope.Drive}, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result 

    Service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() _
    With {.HttpClientInitializer = MyUserCredential, .ApplicationName = "SiteVisitTool"})

End Sub

Private Sub UploadFile(FilePath As String)
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    If Service.ApplicationName <> "SiteVisitTool" Then CreateService()

    Dim TheFile As New Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File
    TheFile.Title = "Deliverables"
    TheFile.Description = "Site Visit data for Google forms"
    TheFile.MimeType = "text/csv"

    Dim ByteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
    Dim Stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ByteArray)

    Dim UploadRequest As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = Service.Files.Insert(TheFile, Stream, TheFile.MimeType)

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    MsgBox("Upload Finished")

End Sub
```

The code runs and I get the message box that the upload has finished.  I have checked Drive and the file doesn't exist.  Sometimes I'm prompted for the account I want to use and then I have to activate it, but I always get the message that it as uploaded.  Highly frustrated!

"SiteVisitTool" is the Project name on Google.

**Should this just be going to the Root folder of Drive?**

Also, if we can get this worked out, I'd like to follow-up and save it to a specific folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a simple fix.  Apparently the website I got this solution from was missing the upload line.  So after you create your Upload request, you need to tell it to upload.

```
Dim UploadRequest As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = Service.Files.Insert(TheFile, Stream, TheFile.MimeType)
UploadRequest.Upload()
```

As for specifying a folder to upload it to, I added where I set the properties of TheFile:

```
TheFile.Parents = New List(Of ParentReference)() From {
            New ParentReference() With {
                .Id = sFolderID
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't ask questions in an answer.